# TinyMce Reloads when I click anything on toolbar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tinymce

The problem is that the tinyMCE(v 4.7.12) editor reloads every time I click on anything on the toolbar. This only happens after one postback. In the first initialization, the editor works fine, but after that it behaves like this. If I refresh the page, the editor works fine again.

**this the error** [Video](https://imgur.com/a/mnbfMEu)

this is the init code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%=_questionText.ClientID%>').tinymce({
            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('init', function (e) {
                    $('#' + e.target.id + '_ifr').removeAttr('title');
                });
            },
            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/tinymce_4.7.12/tinymce.min.js")%>',
               height: 246,
               //cleanup_on_startup:true,
               remove_redundant_brs: true,
               forced_root_block: false,
               branding: false,
               width: 1035,
               relative_urls: false,
               remove_script_host: false,
               // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
               //template_external_list_url: 'lists/template_list.js',
               external_link_list_url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ContentList.aspx?contentType=documents")%>',
               external_image_list_url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ContentList.aspx?contentType=images")%>',
                media_external_list_url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ContentList.aspx?contentType=video")%>',
                plugins: [
                    "image charmap textcolor code upload advlist link <%= (IsHorizontalRuleEnabled? "hr" : "") %> table paste lists"
                ],
                toolbar1: "bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | bullist numlist indent outdent link | <%= (IsHorizontalRuleEnabled? "hr" : "") %> image upload table | charmap code | forecolor backcolor  | styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect ",
                table_default_attributes: {
                    cellpadding: '5px'
                },
                table_default_styles: {
                    width: '50%'
                },
                paste_as_text: true,
                menubar: false,
               init_instance_callback: "tinyMCEInitialized_<%=ClientID%>",
               default_link_target: "_blank",
               //Cause contents to be written back to base textbox on change
               onchange_callback: function (ed) { ed.save(); },
               gecko_spellcheck: true,
               fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 16px 18px 20px 24px 36px"
           });

        //fix for incorrect user input html
        var ok = $('a[id$=_okBtn]');
        ok.attr('data-href', ok.attr('href'));
        ok.removeAttr('href');
        ok.attr('onclick', 'okButtonClick()');
    });
```

I tried removing some tools still behave like this

I expected that though the postback happen this editor functions will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code, where `setup` is.

It appears to be triggered by `$('#<%=_questionText.ClientID%>')` just existing. Odds are JQuery interpreted that as "When a menu item is clicked, setup TinyMCE."

What I think you want is to setup tinymce when one particular item is clicked.

So you need to figure out why `$('#<%=_questionText.ClientID%>')` is targeting all your menu items, and make it only target the specific one you want.

And then you possibly would want to remove the setup from that menu item so subsequent clicks won't make it re-setup TinyMCE.

So you should do something like this:

```
$('#tinyMceMenuItem').on('click',()=> setupTinyMCE())

function setupTinyMCE(){

  // setup TinyMCE
  $('#tinyMceMenuItem').tinymce(...)
  
  // Remove the click event so the user doesn't accidentally run the setup again
  $('#tinyMceMenuItem').off('click')
}
```

Comment: I think you got my question wrong when it first initialize its working fine like all tools are working the bold italic etc but after postback everything stop working just started reloading things on click. Here is a video demonstrating that 
[video](https://imgur.com/a/mnbfMEu)

Comment: @Subham What an excellent gif to attach to your question. You should edit your question and do that, then take out all the code that is not relevant. Your question needs to be clear and concise. Yours is neither, otherwise you would've had a few answers by now. In fact, 99% of the time, when you make it more concise you will discover your own error first. I didn't read all of it, I took a shot, and I'm sorry it didn't solve your problem, but you should work towards making your question as easy to answer as possible.